# How to make Workbox cache case-insensitive

Tags: workbox

I am using Workbox to store offline pages and it works fine except that the URL's need to match case.  If the Workbox cache has a page of 'mysite.com/OfflinePage' and the user types in 'mysite.com/offlinepage' instead, the cache won't find it.

I am using StaleWhileRevalidate for my offline pages and I thought that making a regex with the 'i' argument like so:

```
RegisterStaleWhileRevalidate(new RegExp('/Login', 'i'), 'home');

function RegisterStaleWhileRevalidate(Expression, CacheName) {
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    Expression,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: CacheName,
        matchOptions: {
            ignoreSearch: true,
        },
    })
);
```

}

would do it but no joy.  I'm thinking I may need to trap the url before it gets cached and change it to lower case or something, but totally flying blind here.  Does anyone have an idea what technique I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question: using route criteria that's case-insensitive, and using cache keys inside the strategy that are as well.

There are a number of different ways to handle routing in Workbox; we've switched most of the examples in our documentation away from using [regular expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#matching_a_route_with_a_regular_expression) in favor of [match callbacks](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#handling_a_route_with_a_custom_callback), as that ends up being clearer.

For making a cache key case-insensitive, a [`cacheKeyWillBeUsed`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#:%7E:text=update.-,cacheKeyWillBeUsed,-%3A%20Called) plugin is the cleanest approach.

So something equivalent to what you describe could be accomplished via:

```
function normalizeCacheKeyCase({request}) {
  return request.url.toLowerCase();
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Change this match criteria as you see fit.
  ({url}) => url.pathname.toLowerCase() === '/offlinepage',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    matchOptions: {
      ignoreSearch: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      {cacheKeyWillBeUsed: normalizeCacheKeyCase},
    ],
 })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My new function re-written with Jeff's suggestions:

```
function RegisterStaleWhileRevalidate(Expression, CacheName) {
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    Expression,
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: CacheName,
        matchOptions: {
            ignoreSearch: true,
        },
        plugins: [
            { cacheKeyWillBeUsed: normalizeCacheKeyCase },
        ],
    })
);}

function normalizeCacheKeyCase({ request }) {
    return request.url.toLowerCase();}
```

To call it:

```
RegisterStaleWhileRevalidate(new RegExp('\.(?:css)'), 'css');
```